# how to close css notification badge after user click the link

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a few links in my html page and I want to set up a notification badge (using css) beside my links which I already did but I am not sure how to make the notification badges disappear once the user clicks the link.

CSS:

```
.badge1 {
    position:relative;
}

.badge1[data-badge]:after {
    content:attr(data-badge);
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    font-size:.7em;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    width:30px;height:18px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:18px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0 0 1px #333;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <a href="//dhsintra/MKT/Job Bidding/Upcoming_Job_Bidding_Index.html" <span class="badge1" data-badge="new"></span>Upcoming Job Bidding</a><br>
  <a href="//dhsintra/MKT/7-11 Online Store/7-11_Components_Store_Index.html" <span class="badge1" data-badge="new"></span>7-11 Online Store</a><br>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: you'll probably need javascript, unless your page is reloading, then you'll need some sort of server side language

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: it doesn't work**

I guess you can use this:

```
a:visited .badge1:after{
  content: none;
}
```